# can we get stack trace for lua similar to core dump for C and C++ applications

Tags: lua

we have a daemon written in lua. is it possible to get stack trace when the daemon crashes some thing like a core dump we get in C/C++ languages.

Comment: I haven't used it, but [StackTracePlus](https://github.com/ignacio/StackTracePlus) claims to offer a bit more than debug.traceback, and might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If the "crash" is actually a Lua error, then the standard interpreter shows a traceback. If you're not using the standard interpreter, see how it uses `debug.traceback`.